# Factorization of a particular polynomial in $F_p[x]$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, finite-fields

For an odd prime $p$, define the polynomial $f_p(x) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{p-1} k^{(p-1)/2}x^k$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$. Show that $(x-1)^{(p-1)/2}$ divides
$f_p(x)$, but that $(x-1)^{(p+1)/2}$ does not. Can we say anything interesting about the factorization of the quotient that remains after dividing $f_p(x)$ by $(x-1)^{(p-1)/2}$? I generated a lot of data but couldn't find a discernible pattern.

Comment: By Euler's criterion this is the same as $\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \big( \frac kp \big) x^k$, which is a [Fekete polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fekete_polynomial) other than the constant term.

Comment: Presumably you have verified the first claim in some cases. How many primes $p$ did you check?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I think this is an interesting question. The users who voted to close are worried about lack of context [as described here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/11619). That post is written mostly with homework help seekers in mind, but the requirement applies to all questions. I think addressing my comment (in the question body), would appease them.

Answer (score 0):

I can prove the first claim. My proof is based on the following fact (well known and easy to prove):

> For all primes $p$ and all $j=1,2,\ldots,p-2$ we have the power sum identities (in $\Bbb{F}_p$):
> $$
> \sum_{k=1}^{p-1}k^j=0,
> $$
> but
> $$
> \sum_{k=1}^{p-1}k^{p-1}=-1.
> $$
> The latter being an immediate consequence of Little Fermat.

We can utilize this as follows. Let $L$ denote the differential operator that maps a polynomial $g(x)$ to $Lg(x):=x g'(x)$. By an obvious induction we have
$$L^t f_p(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}k^{t+\frac{p-1}2}x^k$$
for all natural numbers $t$.

The listed power sum results imply that
$$
L^tf_p(1)=\begin{cases}
0,&\ \text{when $t=0,1,\ldots,(p-3)/2$, and}\\
-1,&\ \text{when $t=(p-1)/2$.}\end{cases}
$$
It is easy to see that $L_tf_p(x)$ is a sum containing the term $x^tf_p^{(t)}(x)$ as well as lower order derivatives multiplied by monomials. Therefore this implies the following:

**Corollary.** The order $t$ derivative $f^{(t)}_p(x)$ of the Fekete-polynomial vanishes at $x=1$ when $t=1,2,\ldots,(p-3)/2$, but is non-zero, when $t=(p-1)/2$.

The claim follows from this by the familiar result relating the multiplicity of a zero of a polynomial to the vanishing of the prescribed order of derivatives. Some care needs to be applied when using this result, familiar from characteristic zero, $\Bbb{R}[x]$ in particular. It works in characteristic $p$ as long as the multiplicity of the zero is strictly less than $p$, which is the case here.

Comment: Removed the inconsequential observations about the remaining factors.